# Show that $h(t) =\int_0^t \int_0^s f(x) dxds$ is strictly convex

Tags: real-analysis, integration, general-topology

I am working on the following exercise:

> Let $f: (0,1) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{\ge0}$, be a continuous function such that the set $\{x \in (0,1) \mid f(x) = 0\}$ is a nowhere dense set. Prove that the iterated integral $$h(t) =\int_0^t \int_0^s f(x) dxds$$ is strictly convex.

I do not see how to prove this. Could you give me a hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prove $h'(t)=\displaystyle\int_0^t f(x)dx$ is strictly increasing.

Note that any interval $(a,b)$ containing open interval $(a',b')$ such that $(a',b') \cap \{x \in (0,1) | f(x)=0 \} = \emptyset$, i.e., $f(x) > 0 \ \ \forall x \in (a',b')$.